# Syntax Error (missing operator in query expression)

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

Sir I have a problem, I have this query

```
"SELECT alumni.`ID NO`, alumni.`LAST NAME`, alumni.`GIVEN NAME_MI`, 
alumni.`COURSE`, courses.`CollegeID`, office365alumni.`EmailAddress`, 
office365alumni.`ContactNumber` 
FROM alumni 
LEFT JOIN courses ON alumni.`COURSE` = courses.`ID` 
LEFT JOIN office365alumni ON alumni.`ID NO` = office365alumni.`IDNumber` 
WHERE alumni.`ID NO` = @IDNumber"
```

and it gives me error

```
syntax error (missing operator) in query expression
 'alumni.`COURSE` = courses.`ID` LEFT JOIN office365alumni 
ON alumni.`ID NO` = office365alumni.`IDNumber'.
```

whats wrong with my query? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your column names have spaces in them. Wrap the column names in square brackets and then see how you go:

```
SELECT 
    alumni.[ID NO], 
    alumni.[LAST NAME], 
    alumni.[GIVEN NAME_MI], 
    alumni.[COURSE], 
    courses.[CollegeID], 
    office365alumni.[EmailAddress], 
    office365alumni.[ContactNumber] 
FROM 
    (alumni 
    LEFT JOIN courses ON alumni.[COURSE] = courses.[ID])
    LEFT JOIN office365alumni ON alumni.[ID NO] = office365alumni.[IDNumber] 
WHERE alumni.[ID NO] = @IDNumber
```

Comment: Sir, i still encounter the same error here is my query

"SELECT alumni.[ID NO], alumni.[LAST NAME], alumni.[GIVEN NAME_MI], alumni.[COURSE], courses.[CollegeID], office365alumni.[EmailAddress], office365alumni.[ContactNumber] FROM alumni LEFT JOIN courses ON alumni.[COURSE] = courses.[ID] LEFT JOIN office365alumni ON alumni.[ID NO] = office365alumni.[IDNumber] WHERE alumni.[ID NO] = @IDNumber"

Comment: I have edited the query, try now. You need parenthesis if there are more than one join in access.